# bin/example_reg_map_test error in opencv

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv, face-recognition

I am getting following error while openCV environment setup on my ubuntu 18.04. I have execute some commands which are related to libraries which is require then I have executed following one and shows error

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
      -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
      -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
      -D WITH_TBB=ON \
      -D WITH_V4L=ON \
      -D WITH_QT=ON \
      -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
      -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
      -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

and then following error occurs. Please check this and give solution if you have. Thanks in advance.

```
[ 30%] Built target opencv_photo
[ 30%] Built target opencv_plot
[ 31%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs
[ 32%] Built target opencv_reg
[ 32%] Built target opencv_xphoto
[ 32%] Built target opencv_video
[ 32%] Built target opencv_freetype
[ 35%] Built target opencv_dnn
[ 35%] Built target opencv_hfs
[ 35%] Built target opencv_fuzzy
[ 36%] Built target opencv_img_hash
[ 36%] Built target opencv_xobjdetect
[ 36%] Built target opencv_shape
[ 37%] Built target opencv_videoio
[ 38%] Built target opencv_face
[ 38%] Built target opencv_superres
[ 38%] Built target opencv_highgui
[ 38%] Built target example_hdf_read_write_attributes
[ 38%] Built target example_hdf_create_groups
[ 38%] Built target example_hdf_create_read_write_datasets
[ 39%] Built target opencv_ts
Scanning dependencies of target example_reg_map_test
Scanning dependencies of target example_surface_matching_ppf_load_match
[ 39%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_phase_unwrapping_unwrap
[ 39%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_plot_plot_demo
[ 39%] Building CXX object modules/reg/CMakeFiles/example_reg_map_test.dir/samples/map_test.cpp.o
[ 39%] Building CXX object modules/surface_matching/CMakeFiles/example_surface_matching_ppf_load_match.dir/samples/ppf_load_match.cpp.o
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFIsTiled@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `_TIFFfree@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFNumberOfStrips@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFScanlineSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedTile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBATile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFClose@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFClientOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFRGBAImageOK@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFSetWarningHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFSetErrorHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `_TIFFmalloc@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/phase_unwrapping/CMakeFiles/example_phase_unwrapping_unwrap.dir/build.make:100: recipe for target 'bin/example_phase_unwrapping_unwrap' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/example_phase_unwrapping_unwrap] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4625: recipe for target 'modules/phase_unwrapping/CMakeFiles/example_phase_unwrapping_unwrap.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/phase_unwrapping/CMakeFiles/example_phase_unwrapping_unwrap.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFIsTiled@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `_TIFFfree@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFNumberOfStrips@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFScanlineSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedTile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBATile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFClose@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFClientOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFRGBAImageOK@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFSetWarningHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFSetErrorHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `_TIFFmalloc@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/plot/CMakeFiles/example_plot_plot_demo.dir/build.make:100: recipe for target 'bin/example_plot_plot_demo' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/example_plot_plot_demo] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5165: recipe for target 'modules/plot/CMakeFiles/example_plot_plot_demo.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/plot/CMakeFiles/example_plot_plot_demo.dir/all] Error 2
[ 39%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_surface_matching_ppf_load_match
[ 39%] Built target example_surface_matching_ppf_load_match
[ 39%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_reg_map_test
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFIsTiled@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `_TIFFfree@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFNumberOfStrips@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFScanlineSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedTile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBATile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFClose@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFClientOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFRGBAImageOK@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFSetWarningHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFSetErrorHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `_TIFFmalloc@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/reg/CMakeFiles/example_reg_map_test.dir/build.make:100: recipe for target 'bin/example_reg_map_test' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/example_reg_map_test] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5650: recipe for target 'modules/reg/CMakeFiles/example_reg_map_test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/reg/CMakeFiles/example_reg_map_test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's opencv version and installation problem in ubuntu. Now i have followed following instruction and it's works perfectly.
[https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/)